# ElasticSearch query using Nest - Match Field to one of a few options

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an elastic index with a keyword "user_id" field.
I would like to get all documents that are of a group of users.

```
{
...,
"user_id": "031aeda2-b552-4a16-9ae6-68a24492e252",
...,
}
```

I want to get documents that belong to one or more user_ids, i.e. - get documents that have user_id:
"031aeda2-b552-4a16-9ae6-68a24492e252"
or
"031fffa2-c552-4a16-9ae6-68a24492e141"
or
...

How can I do it on Nest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since standard analyzer  provides grammar based tokenization, it will split your text on hypen , so use on keyword field

Nest has two syntax

Fluent and Object initializer

Using fluent syntax above can be resolved using [Terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) query.

```
_elasticClient                
 .Search<Users>(s => s
 .From(0).Size(10)
 .Query(q => q.Terms(p => p.Field(c => c.user_id.Suffix("keyword"))
                                        .Terms(new List<string> { "1" }))));
```

*Replace Users with your model.

If you need to dynamically create query, you can use object initializer syntax of NEST

Comment: Maybe a silly question as I'm new to Nest - can I somehow do the should part in a foreach loop? my search values comes as a dynamic list

Comment: @DaniToker I have updated the answer. For your problem terms query will work.  Should would been needed if search fields were different

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work, tried exactly the same query (without the from and size for now) and it yielded no results

Comment: @DaniToker what is the error?. Have you replaced User with your model and "term1", "term2" with your values

Comment: This is the relevant part of the query:
q.Terms(p => p.Field(x => x.UserId).Terms(userIds));

This is the response:
{
  "result": {
    "value": [],
    "formatters": [],
    "contentTypes": [],
    "declaredType": null,
    "statusCode": 200
  },
  "value": null
}

Comment: @DaniToker add enable debug mode ex. var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool)
    .DefaultIndex("index_name")
    .EnableDebugMode()
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);  in queryByTerm  iunder debug information you will get actual query(query-dsl)  run that in kibana and check if it is returning result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234259/discussion-between-jaspreet-chahal-and-dani-toker).

Comment: Fixed! this is the solution and in addition had to add the keyword suffix - then it worked